# How do I use Kibana to visualise data in an IBM Databases for Elasticsearch deployment?

Tags: database, docker, elasticsearch, ibm-cloud, kibana

I have an [IBM Cloud Databases for Elasticsearch](https://www.ibm.com/products/databases-for-elasticsearch) deployment. I want to connect to it using Kibana to visualise my data. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing this:
One is that you can run Kibana locally using Docker. You will need your ES host name, port, username, password and the version of your ES deployment.
Run the command below, replacing the placeholders with your service details:

```bash
docker container run -it --name "kibana" \
  -p 5601:5601 \
  --env 'ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["https://yourhostname:yourport"]' \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=admin" \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=yourpassword" \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_ENABLED=true" \
  --env "SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0" \
  --env "ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE=none" \
  docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:version_of_your_ES_deployment
```

Alternatively, you can use IBM Code Engine to deploy Kibana in a serverless way and make it accessible on a public web URL. This would allow others who have the service credentials to also access the Kibana instance from elsewhere.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-elasticsearch?topic=databases-for-elasticsearch-kibana-code-engine-icd-elasticsearch) to run Kibana on Code Engine using Terraform.

> Note that both the above methods use `ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE=none`, so although the traffic between Kibana and Elasticsearch is encrypted, the Elasticsearch service is not verified against the CA certificate provided by IBM Databases for Elasticsearch credentials.